# EmguCV works sometimes

Tags: vb.net, windows, macos, opencv, emgucv

I have a question. Yesterday I started a project in VB.net 2010 Express. I used EmguCV in it, it worked perfect. Today I reopened the project to continue coding. I started the project by clicking the green play button (I did not change anything).

You probably already guessed it... It does not work. It returns a NullReference error.

My code:

```
'
'  Copyright (C) 2004-2013 by EMGU. All rights reserved.
'

Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure
Imports Emgu.Util
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1
    Dim capturez As Capture = New Capture
    Sub LoadProcess()

        Dim img As Image(Of Bgr, Byte)
        img = capturez.RetrieveBgrFrame()

        'Load the object detector
        Dim faceDetector As New CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

        'Convert the image to Grayscale
        Dim imgGray As Image(Of Gray, Byte) = img.Convert(Of Gray, Byte)()

        For Each face As Rectangle In faceDetector.DetectMultiScale( _
                           imgGray, _
                           1.1, _
                           10, _
                           Size.Empty, _
                           Size.Empty)
            img.Draw(face, New Bgr(Color.White), 1)
            Form1.Label1.Text = (face.Left / Form1.ImageBox1.Width) * 100
            Form1.Label2.Text = (face.Top / Form1.ImageBox1.Height) * 100
            If ((face.Left / Form1.ImageBox1.Width) * 100) > 50 Then
                Form1.Label3.Text = "Naar rechts"
            ElseIf ((face.Left / Form1.ImageBox1.Width) * 100) < 50 Then
                Form1.Label3.Text = "Naar links"
            End If

            If ((face.Top / Form1.ImageBox1.Height) * 100) > 50 Then
                Form1.Label4.Text = "Naar omlaag"
            ElseIf ((face.Top / Form1.ImageBox1.Height) * 100) < 50 Then
                Form1.Label4.Text = "Naar omhoog"
            End If
        Next

        'Show the image
        Form1.ImageBox1.Image = img
        Form1.ImageBox1.FunctionalMode = UI.ImageBox.FunctionalModeOption.Minimum
    End Sub

End Module
```

I added three references: Emgu.CV.dll, Emgu.CV.UI.dll and Emgu.Util.dll. 
My computer is a MacBook Pro with Windows 8.1 as a dual boot.

I do not think that there is something wrong with my code, side it worked yesterday!!!

The error occurs in:

```
Dim imgGray As Image(Of Gray, Byte) = img.Convert(Of Gray, Byte)()
```

I hope anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance,
Lars Jansen
The Netherlands

Comment: I don't know you "skill level". But a [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is a common exception. Knowing what this means is quite valuable. The first potential NRE i can see of this code is the `Form1`.

Comment: Is Form1 a problem? It worked the other day, so why doesn't it work now?

Comment: If a NRE is thrown at the line you say i'm pretty sure that the variable `img` is `Nothing`. If so, and you call the method `img.Convert(Of Gray, Byte)()`, it will throw this error. The reason is probably that the method `capturez.RetrieveBgrFrame()` returns nothing. So i think you should start there.

Comment: I found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182299/why-does-retrievebgrframe-return-null) which **might** be of some use:)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I tried changing it to Module1.capturez.RetrieveBgrFrame() and such but it won't work. Is there anything I have to "see" in your last answer? :P

Comment: I'm not familiar with this api, but if you check [docs](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/html/d72e902f-e241-1d3c-d5ea-ab24a0be00d4.htm) it says "Retrieve a Bgr image frame after Grab()". I can't see any call to `Grab()` in your code.

Comment: It looks like you'll have to do somthing like calling `Grab()` **before** calling `RetrieveBgrFrame()`. If you don't, i guess it only returns a null value, thus the NRE.

Comment: If I just call: `capturez.grab()`, the same error occurs.
BUT when I call this: `MsgBox(capturez.Grab())`

Comment: ... I get a LOT of msgboxes but it works! Why?

Comment: As I said, i don't know this API. You could post the code for `Form1` and maybe the `Main()` if you have a custom entry point. I also suggest you read the documentation;D

Comment: But using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` is also not good. It slows it down a lot. Do you know another way to 'delay' this sort of things?

Comment: Never mind! It works ;D Thank you very much Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå!

Comment: How did you fix it? It might be useful for others to know.

Comment: `If firsttime Then
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            firsttime = False
        End If
`